# How to loop a HTTPS requests.post from csv data

Tags: https, python-requests

I want to loop post requests for data from a csv.

csv file (has 2 columns )=

```
agentLicenseID(x)   licenseExpirationDate(y)
271844  6/20/2021
271847  6/30/2021
271848  5/21/2021
```

```py
body = {'sid':API_SID,'key':API_KEY,  'agentLicenseID':x,'licenseExpirationDate':y }

response = requests.post(url=UPD_URL,data=body)
```

I intend on looping the response for different values of x and y ( agentLicenseID and licenseExpirationDate) from the csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", sep=r"\s+")  # <-- change the separator if it's different

for x, y in zip(df["agentLicenseID"], df["licenseExpirationDate"]):
    body = {
        "sid": API_SID,
        "key": API_KEY,
        "agentLicenseID": x,
        "licenseExpirationDate": y,
    }
    response = requests.post(url=UPD_URL, data=body)

    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the logic now. However I still seem to be getting an error: KeyError: 'agentLicenseID'. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with how the csv is being read by the system? I called df after defining the variable (pd.read.csv) and got the following output:   agentLicenseID,licenseExpirationDate
0                     271844,3/12/2021
1                     271847,6/22/2021
2                      271848,5/5/2021

Comment: Actually just figured it out, the issue was with the separator, needed to change it to ",". Thanks a ton really appreciate it!